# Ggplot2 map with colored background and coord_map()

Tags: shapefile, r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot some cities stored in my rda file `naobrazokSR.rda` on a map from `GADM` while having a background of the map in color `#2C3E4F`. Without using the `coord_map()` this works as intended but looks deformed. After using the `coord_map()` white bars appear on top and bottom. I'm trying to use the plot inside shiny application and I believe this can be solved by fixing the aspect ratio somehow, but I'm not sure how. Is there a way to change the whitebars to my color without adjusting the aspect ratio?

```
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)
SVK <- readRDS("D:\\Downloads\\SVK_adm1.rds") 
alfa = 0.5
load("D:\\Downloads\\naobrazokSR.rda")
p <- ggplot() + geom_polygon(data=SVK, aes(long,lat,group=group))
p <- p + geom_path(data=SVK, aes(long,lat, group=group), color="white",size=0.1)
p <- p + geom_point(aes(x=pomoc$X1, y=pomoc$X2) , size=2,col = "red", alpha=alfa) 
p <- p + theme(axis.line=element_blank(),axis.text.x=element_blank(),
           axis.text.y=element_blank(),axis.ticks=element_blank(),
           axis.title.x=element_blank(),
           axis.title.y=element_blank(),legend.position="none",
           panel.background=element_rect(fill = "#2C3E4F", colour = "#2C3E4F"),
           panel.border=element_blank(),panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
           panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
           plot.background= element_rect(fill = "#2C3E4F", colour = "#2C3E4F")) 
p <- p + coord_map()
p
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cowplot` to the rescue!

I used a different vector file for this example. White borders on left and right sides:

[image]

Use `cowplot` and set again `panel.background`:

```
library(cowplot)
ggdraw(p) + theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#2C3E4F", colour = "#2C3E4F"))
```

[image]

---

Work-around with `ggplot2` and image export:

```
pdf(filename = '~/test.pdf',width = 3000, height = 2000,bg = "#2C3E4F") # could be jpeg and png also
p <- ggplot() + geom_polygon(data=SVK, aes(long,lat,group=group))
p <- p + geom_path(data=SVK, aes(long,lat, group=group), color="white",size=0.1)
p <- p + geom_point(aes(x=pomoc$X1, y=pomoc$X2) , size=2,col = "red", alpha=alfa) 
p <- p + theme(axis.line=element_blank(),axis.text.x=element_blank(),
           axis.text.y=element_blank(),axis.ticks=element_blank(),
           axis.title.x=element_blank(),
           axis.title.y=element_blank(),legend.position="none",
           panel.background=element_blank(),
           panel.border=element_blank(),panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
           panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
           plot.background= element_blank()) 
p <- p + coord_map()
p
dev.off()
```

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly, but to me the solution seems rather strange. It looks like it only redraws the same plot on a colored rectangle. Why does this not work in basic ggplot? Can it be solved by only using ggplot2 library or is there a bug in the order of operations thats solved by cowplot? Or is this another question i should rather post on StackOverflow?

Comment: `cowplot` use grob method, it transforms `ggplot` object to `grob` and uses a grid to place the plot. Using `ggplot2`, you have to change `xlim` and `ylim` to fit your device size (in terms of width/height) or to use the approach that I include in my answer, so check the edit